# Composition of a rotation and a traslation is a rotation

Tags: geometry, isometry

Assuming that I know that:

1) A plane isometry is either a rotation, a traslation, a reflection, or a glide reflection

2) Every isometry can be expressed as a product of reflections,

3) Rotations and translations are pair isometries (in the sense that the number of reflections at which they can be expressed is pair),

4) A a rotation is product of two reflections through two lines that intersect and a traslation is a product of two reflextions through two parallel lines

what's is wrong in the following proof of the question:

Given $\tau=\sigma_{a}\sigma_{b}$ where $a || b$, and $\rho=\sigma_{a'}\sigma_{b'}$ where $a'$ and $b'$ are not parallel, then $\tau\rho=\sigma_{b}\sigma_{a}\sigma_{a'}\sigma_{b'}$ is a pair isometry, so it can only be a rotation or a translation. But in order it to be a translation, $a,b,a',b'$ must be parallel, and we know that $a'$ and $b'$ are not parallel, so the product is not a translation, so it must be a rotation.

Comment: How do you know that the resulting transformation can’t be decomposed some other way as a reflection in two parallel lines?

Comment: The transformation is composed as a rotation and a translation. Every rotation is a composition of reflections of lines that intersect. Altought a translation can be put as a composition of two rotations, in that case those two rotations can be decomposed as two reflections and the resulting transformation has two reflections that are parallel lines. So the final result is that, in any case, a translation has to have two parallel lines.

Comment: That doesn’t answer my question. Why must the specific lines that you used to construct the transformation be parallel? Why can’t there be some *other* two parallel lines that can be used to decompose the constructed transformation? I don’t see how you’re eliminating this possibility.

Comment: The lines a, b, a', b' are arbitrary. What I'm trying to say is that, in any case, by the properties of reflections and translations, these lines must have a series of properties that would share among every other decomposition.

Comment: You’re asserting without any justification that one of these properties is that all four of the lines are parallel.

Comment: Because a translation does not have fixed points and when two reflections "intersect" (well, the axis over which are defined), then there is a fixed point, and that makes for a rotation.

Comment: Then you should write *that*. It’s much clearer than what you’ve got.

Answer (score 1):

A translation $T$ of vector $\vec v$ is the product of the reflections about ANY two parallel lines, perpendicular to $\vec v$ and with distance $|\vec v|/2$ between them. A rotation $R$ of center $O$ and angle $\theta$ is the product of the reflections about ANY two lines, intersecting at $O$ and forming an angle $\theta/2$ between them.

If $r$ is the line passing through $O$ and perpendicular to $\vec v$, there exist then two other lines, $s$ (parallel to $r$) and $t$ (passing through $O$), such that $T=\sigma_r\circ\sigma_s$ and $R=\sigma_t\circ\sigma_r$. It follows that
$$
R\circ T=\sigma_t\circ\sigma_r\circ\sigma_r\circ\sigma_s=\sigma_t\circ\sigma_s.
$$
But $t$ and $s$ are not parallel and form the same angle as $t$ and $r$, hence this is a rotation $R'$ of angle $\theta$. The center $O'$ of this rotation is located at the intersection of $s$ and $t$.

Answer (score 0):

You reasoning is correct. I just dislike the sentence: "But in order it to be a translation, $a,b,a′,b′$ must be parallel. Actually just $a',b'$ must be parallel and they can interesct $a,b$, lines that are already parallel.

Comment: I think that if a' and b' were parallel then the composition of $\sigma_{a'}$ and $\sigma_{b'}$ would not be a rotation but a translation.

Comment: True, but $a',b$ do not have to be parallel and it could be still a transtation in the end, that is what I wanted to say